# In Revit C#, crop region visibility

Tags: c#, view, revit-api

In Revit `C#`, I've looped through the view elements and grabbed the parameter `VIEWER_CROP_REGION_VISIBLE`, I want to turn the bool visibly on or off.
I should be able to "Get", then "Set"

I've tried `AsValueString`, Yes, No, it didn't change the visibility

*how do you turn the visibility on/off*

Comment: if (viewName.EndsWith("doc") || viewName.EndsWith("struct") || viewName.EndsWith("elec"))
                {               
                    View viewSymbol = viewElement as View;

                    Parameter cropBoxVisibleParam = viewElement.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.VIEWER_CROP_REGION_VISIBLE);

                    string visValue = cropBoxVisibleParam.AsValueString(); // this returned a "Yes" ??

                    cropBoxVisibleParam.Set("No");

                    visValue = cropBoxVisibleParam.AsValueString();

Comment: OK, got it to work as integer:                      int visValue = cropBoxVisibleParam.AsInteger(); 
                    cropBoxVisibleParam.Set(0);

                    visValue = cropBoxVisibleParam.AsInteger();

Comment: It is usually preferred on StackOverflow to post the updates to the question rather than the comments. I think your approach works, as shown, using set(0) or set(1), however, it may be more straightforward to just set that property on the `View` class. See my answer posted below.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an easier way to tackle the issue, since `CropBoxVisible` is a setable property of the `View` class.

```cs
    [Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
    internal class ToggleCropRegion : IExternalCommand
    {
        public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
        {
            using (var t = new Transaction(commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document, "ToggleCropBox"))
            {
                t.Start();
                var currentView = commandData.View;
                currentView.CropBoxVisible = !currentView.CropBoxVisible;
                t.Commit();
            }


            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
    }
```